# Why do we need the chain rule(s) for partial derivatives with multiple independent variables?

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

Is the generalized chain rule for partial derivatives with multiple independent variables only for convenience, or are there problems that *require* its use?

The questions I have seen so far are at worst like:

> Let $w(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ where $x=4re^t$, $y=-3te^r$, $z=e^{rt}$.
>
> Find $\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$.

It doesn't seem like using the chain rule here saves much work (if any?), does it? Are there other instances that actually *require* the chain rule?

Comment: I've discussed this issue several times before on this site. Sometimes you don't have explicit functions for $x,y,z$ in terms of $r,t$, but you know their values and their derivatives at a certain point $(r_0,t_0)$. Then the chain rule will give you the derivatives of the composition. By the way, you're still using the chain rule when you plug in the given functions; it's just one step less conceptual.

Comment: In specific instances, the multivariable chain rule often can be alternatively calculated using the single variable chain rule. See https://ihxrelation.blogspot.com/2014/12/chain-rules.html

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin for mentioning that... I *did* search but didn't but a direct answer.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388853/computing-the-speed-of-decreasing-of-the-temperature-of-a-function-that-depends/396590#396590) is an example. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590808/derivative-of-a-multivariable-composite-functions/4590846#4590846) is another.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite example is $F(t)=\int_a^uf(v,x)dx$ where $u$ and $v$ are functions of $t$.For example, $$F(t)=\int_{-1}^{3t+1}e^{tx^2}dx$$ Find (a)$F^{\prime}(t)$ (b)$F^{\prime}(0)$. The only way I know how do such a question is by Leibniz's Rule, which is just the chain rule for 2 variables, combined with differentiaion through an  integral for differentiation with respect to $v$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus for differentiation with respect to $u$. I agree with you completely that the examples given in many texts are silly.

Comment: I am doing a foreign language video course featuring a professor whose foreign language accent is so-so. At first I felt smugly superior to him, but I've started to suspect that he is a subtle and brilliant instructor for using that accent.